# Angular2 no changing in browser when modify typescript file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using angular2 with Visual Studio 2015.
I completely new at angular2 so I'm discovering it step by step, right now I have an app.component.ts, displaying in html file, and everything works but when I'm making changes like the content of template in the typescript file nothing's moving, I style have the older content I tried to rebuild the project, close the project and re open it, tried to disable the cache like said in a topic but nothing works, what am I missing ??

Comment: compilation ts -> js is automatic in Visual Studio, you dont need any console command. possible errors in ts file (js file changed?) or angular not installed (see guide on www.typescriptlang.org)

Comment: It was working, I created a component and the typescript compiled to javascript it displays what i wrote in the typescript file but now I want to make changes it 's not working , js file is not changed at all, when I run the application it displays the old files without any changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the typescript to javascript in order to see the changes. Simply run npm tsc in your console and your script will compile.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using command line I would suggest to install `@angular/cli` package. If you use `ng serve` your app will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.